# Nested Classes C++

Tags: c++, nested-class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [nested classes C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571355/nested-classes-c)
>   [nested class access control in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173520/nested-class-access-control-in-c)

I'm a little confused as to what access a nested class has to the members of an enclosing class. What is the relationship it shares with the outer class?

Answer (score 2):

The nested class does not have any special access to the enclosing class that would not be available to any other class - it can see public members, etc. The nesting only provides a useful scoping mechanism for nested class, but doesn't change its behavior or capabilities.

Comment: What about typenames such as vector>int<::iterator, can the iterator class use typename int to type objects inside it's class? I revered the >< because it hides them.

Comment: In the general case, no, the nested class wouldn't have special information. In the specific case of vector's iterator class, that class is actually a class template instance that takes the same type parameter as the container class. It's also the case, though, that vector has a value_type typedef of it's type parameter, and that's often used in generic programming.

Comment: @rubixibuc: To format code, put it in backticks: `\`vector<int>::iterator\``

Answer (score 1):

This might help you : [nested class access control in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173520/nested-class-access-control-in-c). It is not exacly what you asked, but gives some interesting informations.