# Is it possible to construct a class inside of a class?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

Is it possible to create a class within another class? Is treating my class declaration as a member function. Here is my code:

```
struct Handler{
  int *_value = nullptr;
  Handler(int& value)
  {
    _value = &value;
  }
};
struct action{
  int _value = 0;
  Handler handler(_value);
};
```

So I want the `_value` in the struct Handler have the same adress with the `_value` in struct action, so when I change one of them, the other one will have the same value.

Comment: Make it `Handler handler{_value};` (note braces). [Demo](https://rextester.com/DARLK26309)

Comment: Thank you! now it is working because its not treated as a member function!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Classes C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827637/nested-classes-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) only support brace or equals initializer, but not parentheses initializer. So you can write it as

```
Handler handler{_value};           // list initialization (since C++11)
```

or

```
Handler handler = Handler(_value); // copy initialization
```