# Comparator that requires access to private members of class

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Basic structure of my code is

```
class Foo{
  vector<string> _lines;
  vector<int> _n;
  public:
  ...
  bool Comp(int i, int j){
    return something that depends on _lines;
  }
  ...
  void doSomething(){
    std::sort(_n.begin(), _n.end(), Comp);
  }
  ...
};
```

But I get

```
error: no matching function for call to 
‘sort(std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator, 
std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)
```

How can I resolve this problem **WITHOUT COPYING THE VECTORS?** (because these vectors are very very big 17179508 strings to be precise).

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` expects a binary predicate taking two ints in this case. A member function takes an implicit first parameter, so in all `Foo::Comp` takes three parameters. You could pass a non-member function, or a static member function, but neither of these would have access to `Foo`'s data members. The simples way is to use `std::bind` to bind `this` to the first parameter of the member function:

```
#include <functional> // for std::bind
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Foo{
  vector<string> _lines;
  vector<int> _n;
 public:
  ...

  bool Comp(int i, int j){
    return something that depends on _lines;
  }
  ...
  void sort(){
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    std::sort(_n.begin(), _n.end(), std::bind(Comp, this, _1, _2));
  }
  ...
};
```

Comment: This isn't the problem: The problem is that `Comp` is a non-static member function that hasn't has `this` bound.

Comment: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Foo::_lines’ in function Comp

Comment: @PratikDeoghare My first answer was total nonsense. I have edited it.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo::Comp(Foo* const, const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&)’

Comment: @PratikDeoghare more typos, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious initial suggestion is to aggregate your `int` and `string` into a struct or `std::pair`, have a single vector with the aggregate in it, and then sort that vector of aggregates.

But if the two vectors are in fact independent, I would suggest using an external predicate, *instead* of your `Comp` method:

```
struct Comp
{
    explicit Comp(vector<string>& lines) : lines_(lines) { }
    bool operator()(int i, int j) const
    {
        return something that depends on lines_;
    }

    vector<string>& lines_;
};
```

Then call it:

```
void doSomething()
{
    std::sort(_n.begin(), _n.end(), Comp(_lines));
}
```

Comment: Will this copy create a copy of lines? Because number of string in lines is 17179508. :)

Comment: @PratikDeoghare no, it will not. But the solution you chose will :-)

Comment: @Pratik Deoghare No copy of `_lines` will be made.

Comment: `std::pair` is probably not a good solution; the elements certainly have more meaningful names than `first` and `second`.  But it sounds like he's trying to map `int` to `string` (but I'm not sure); this may be the error to begin with (and perhaps he should drop the vector of `int` completely).  But your answer is more or less the right approach if he doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

What about using your object as the comparator itself. This compiles on gcc 4.6:

```
class Foo{
  std::vector<std::string> _lines;
  std::vector<int> _n;
  public:

  bool operator()(int i, int j){
    return false;
  }
  void doSomething(){
    std::sort(_n.begin(), _n.end(), *this);
  }
};
```

---

Edit:

Turns out that was not such a good idea, copying an object with 17M strings would incur a huge penalty. A nested class, taking a pointer, could be used instead. That would also allow us to have different comparators:

```
class Foo
{
  std::vector<std::string> _lines;
  std::vector<int> _n;

  class Bar
  {
  public:
      Bar( const Foo * foo ) : _foo( foo ) {}
      bool operator()( int i, int j )
      {
          act on _foo->_lines
      }
  private:
      const Foo * _foo;
  };

public:

  void doSomething(){
    std::sort(_n.begin(), _n.end(), Bar(this));
  }
};
```

Comment: That's not really a good idea.  What happens if in one case, you need a less than comparison, and in another an equals comparison?

Comment: @PratikDeoghare beware, this makes a copy of the `Foo` instance.

Comment: And it's not clear to me what is being compared.  `std::sort` cannot call a function taking `int`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: sort is applied on a vector of ints

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Yes.  I've reread the question:-).  (And deleted my answer to a completely different question.)

Comment: _lines is private. How can _foo access _lines using _foo->_lines? It works but I want to know why.

Comment: @PratikDeoghare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173520/nested-class-access-control-in-c