# Inner class access to private members of outer, according to ISO 2003

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, nested-class, c++03

As described in ISO C++ 2003

> §11.8 Nested classes [class.access.nest]
>
> The members of a nested class have no special access to members of an
>   enclosing class, nor to classes or functions that have granted
>   friendship to an enclosing class; the usual access rules (clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed. The members of an enclosing class have no special
>   access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (clause
>   11) shall be obeyed.
>
> [Example:
>
> ```
> class E {
>     int x;
>
>     class B { };
>
>     class I {
>         B b; // error: E::B is private ERROR 1
>         int y;
>         void f(E* p, int i)
>         {
>             p->x = i; // error: E::x is private ERROR 2
>         }
>     };
>
>     int g(I* p)
>     {
>         //return p->y; // error: I::y is private ERROR 3
>     }
> };
>
> int main()
> {}
> ```
>
> —end example]

So I think that [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3dd1797207d302a8) and [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c46ac28b74bdc24c) are wrong as they compile this code successfully.

Or do I understand something wrong?

Comment: Related to [CWG DR #45](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#45)

Comment: Related/duplicate of [nested class access control in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3173520/)

Answer (score 0):

Standard says about "have no *special* access", but not about "have **no** access at all". Nested class is a same member of outer class as any other member.

It is not clearly said in C++03 standard, but C++11 contains it explicitly:

> 11.7 Nested classes [class.access.nest]
>
> 1 A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour has changed since 2003. The relevant clause in Working Draft N4926 (C++17) now reads:

> §11.7 Nested classes [class.access.nest]
>
> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of
> an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
> shall be obeyed.

So the access is one way: nested class members can access enclosing class members, but not vice versa.

For instance:

```
class Enclosing
{
  int n;
  class Nested
  {
    int n;
    int f (Enclosing& E)
    {
      return E.n; // OK
    }
  } ;
  int f (Nested& N)
  {
    return N.n; // Error: Nested::n is private
  }
} ;
```

Comment: AND vice versa, they are equal in access rights to each other.

Comment: @VladislavYaroslavlev: Not in C++17 they don't.

Comment: what exactly forbids the access? The rule says: "no special access", not "no access". Any private member can see any other private member.
That clause (11.7) is in C++11 already, not in C++17.

Comment: @VladislavYaroslavlev: What forbids it is the phrase "the usual access rules shall be obeyed." I have added an example to my answer. Try it with C++14 or C++17 enabled.